# Getting the current playback offset for an audio element

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm trying to create a custom audio player, but I can't find a property on the audio element that shows the current playback time.

HTMLMediaElement.played sounds correct, but after the file has played once it just returns the whole range of time.

Comment: Isn’t this `HTMLMediaElement.prototype.currentTime`?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how I missed that one.